# full name of the user in a User Field

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, spfield

I have a list which among other fields contains a user field, shows domain\username. Is there a way to show full name of the user in a User field?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the list settings, click on the column, and change the drop down to full name.